# KeyError in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord import client
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import json
import time

class AFK(commands.Cog):
    '''
    Class containing AFK commands/system.
    '''
    def __init__(self, client, *args, **kwargs):
        self.client = client
    async def update_data(self, afk, user):
        if not f'{user.id}' in afk:
            afk[f'{user.id}'] = {}
            afk[f'{user.id}']['AFK'] = 'False'
            afk[f'{user.id}']['reason'] = 'None'
    
    async def time_formatter(self, seconds: float):
        '''
        Convert UNIX time to human readable time.
        '''
        minutes, seconds = divmod(int(seconds), 60)
        hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
        days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)
        tmp = ((str(days) + "d, ") if days else "") + \
            ((str(hours) + "h, ") if hours else "") + \
            ((str(minutes) + "m, ") if minutes else "") + \
            ((str(seconds) + "s, ") if seconds else "")
        return tmp[:-2]
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        with open('db/afk.json', 'r') as f:
            afk = json.load(f)
        
        for user_mention in message.mentions:
            if afk[f'{user_mention.id}']['AFK'] == 'True':
                if message.author.bot: 
                    return
                
                reason = afk[f'{user_mention.id}']['reason']
                meth = int(time.time()) - int(afk[f'{user_mention.id}']['time'])
                been_afk_for = await self.time_formatter(meth)
                await message.reply(f'<:afk:925069503010832424>┃`{user_mention.name}` **ist seit __{been_afk_for}__ abwesend**: <a:news1:925069477505273946> \n> {reason}')
                
                meeeth = int(afk[f'{user_mention.id}']['mentions']) + 1
                afk[f'{user_mention.id}']['mentions'] = meeeth
                with open('db/afk.json', 'w') as f:
                    json.dump(afk, f)
        
        if not message.author.bot:
            await self.update_data(afk, message.author)

            if afk[f'{message.author.id}']['AFK'] == 'True':                
                meth = int(time.time()) - int(afk[f'{message.author.id}']['time'])
                been_afk_for = await self.time_formatter(meth)
                mentionz = afk[f'{message.author.id}']['mentions']

                await message.reply(f'<:afk1:925069501433794561>┃{message.author.mention} **ist wieder da!**\n_Dein AFK-Status wurde entfernt._')
                
                afk[f'{message.author.id}']['AFK'] = 'False'
                afk[f'{message.author.id}']['reason'] = 'None'
                afk[f'{message.author.id}']['time'] = '0'
                afk[f'{message.author.id}']['mentions'] = 0
                
                with open('db/afk.json', 'w') as f:
                    json.dump(afk, f)
                
                try:
                    await message.author.edit(nick=f'{message.author.display_name[4:]}')
                except:
                    print(f'I wasnt able to edit [{message.author}].')
        
        with open('afk.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(afk, f)
        
    @commands.command()
    async def afk(self, ctx, *, reason=None):
        with open('db/afk.json', 'r') as f:
            afk = json.load(f)

        if not reason:
            reason = 'Kein Grund angegeben'
        
        await self.update_data(afk, ctx.message.author)
        afk[f'{ctx.author.id}']['AFK'] = 'True'
        afk[f'{ctx.author.id}']['reason'] = f'{reason}'
        afk[f'{ctx.author.id}']['time'] = int(time.time())
        afk[f'{ctx.author.id}']['mentions'] = 0

        await ctx.reply(f'<:afk:925069503010832424>┃{ctx.message.author.mention} **ist nun abwesend**: <a:news1:925069477505273946>\n> {reason}')

        with open('db/afk.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(afk, f)
        try:
            await ctx.author.edit(nick=f'AFK┃{ctx.author.display_name}')
        except:
            print(f'I wasnt able to edit [{ctx.message.author}].')

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(AFK(client))
```

**I get if i use this code like every 10 Minutes this Error Message:**

File "/home/container/cogs/afk.py", line 39, in on_message
if afk[f'{user_mention.id}']['AFK'] == 'True':
KeyError: '890990740220547072'

**I tried everything to fix this but nothing seems to work. And i dont know anymore what i can do to fix that problem.**

Comment: Apparently that key (890990740220547072) does not exist. You need to debug why that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `afk` has no `890990740220547072` key

If key existence is not mandatory, you should change `if` condition to:

```
if f'{user_mention.id}' in afk and afk[f'{user_mention.id}'].get('AFK', False) == True:
  ...
  do something
  ...
```

Also, I don't know why you using `f'{user_mention.id}'` instead of `user_mention.id`, but that means that your `id` will be converted to string (same as `str(user_mention.id)`). If your json original value is number you should use `afk[user_mention.id]` without conversions